# Populate select with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a table that includes the taxonomic name of a species. So there are separate columns for each species, domain, kingdom, phylum, etc. I am using a select boxes for each of these classifications, and what I need to happen is when the first one (Domain) is selected, the database is queried to get all the kingdomes where domain is the value of the previous select.

Here's what I have for my PHP in 'search.php':

```
<select name="domain" id="domain">
<option value="standard">-- Domain --</option>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_domains, MYSQL_NUM))
{
  echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
} ?>
</select>

<select name="kingdom" id="kingdom" >
<option value="standard">-- Kingdom --</option>
<?php 
        $result = array();
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];
    $get_kingdoms = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT sci_kingdom FROM tbl_lifedata WHERE sci_domain = $domain");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_kingdoms, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
         $result[] = array(
             'name' => $row[0]
         );
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
</select>
```

And this is what I have in my jquery:

```
$('#domain').change(function() {
    $domain = $('#domain option:selected').val();

    if ($domain == 'standard') {
        $('#kingdom').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('.btn-cover').text('Select a Domain:');
    } else {
        $('#kingdom').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('.btn-cover').text('Select a Kingdom:');
    }
});

$('#kingdom').change(function() {
    $kingdom = $('#kingdom option:selected').val();

    if ($kingdom == 'standard') {
        $('#domain').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#phylum').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('.btn-cover').text('Select a Kingdom:');

    } else {
        $('#domain').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#phylum').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('.btn-cover').text('Select a Phylum:');
        $.post("search.php", {
            'domain': option
        }, function(data) {
            var sel = $("#kingdom");
            sel.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                sel.append('<option>' + data[i].name + '</option>');
            }
        }, "json");
    }
});​
```

I'm having the most trouble understanding how the .post() function works. I know exactly what I want to do, just not exactly how to do.

My goal:
 - obtain the value of the domain select box when it is changed
 - use that value in the mysql query to get the relevant kingdoms
 - execute the query using jquery and then populate the kingdom select box

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found out where the error is occuring yet? While I see a vague question, I don't see a specific issue. Is the server not receiving the data? is it not registering when sent back? Debugging is a must here. **Also** What version of jQuery are you using? I'd suggest using `.prop()` instead of `.attr() and removeAttr()`.

Comment: By the way, general understanding, $.post("url.ext", { key: "value", key: "value"}, function(data){ //data contains server response}, 'dataType'); the dataType by default will detect the data being *returned* from the server. if you do not construct and send your JSON object properly in the backend, then it will not work if you explicitly define `json` as the datatype.

Comment: The problem is I'm not exactly sure where the error is occurring or how to debug this one. I'm sorry for the vagueness. For the $.post what do 'key' and 'value' correspond to?

Comment: Key is how you access the object when you receive it in the back end. if the 'key' was 'george' and the value was 'is cool', then if you did $_POST['george'], the value would be 'is cool'. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, for debugging purposes, I prefer Firefox with the Firebug addon. After installnig Firebug, simply hit F12 to open the tools window. Invoke the $_POST action, and then check the 'NET' panel. Click the '+' symbol next to the request. You will then see several smaller boxes. You can look at the data being sent (to see if it's sending the proper data), and you can look at the response (to see what's being sent back to you). if either one of these are blank, or report a PHP error, it will give you headwind to move forward.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, and I will definitely try that. Thank you!